# Execute some blocks in Camunda after a process instance is deleted

Tags: java, business-process-management, camunda, camunda-modeler

I am trying to find out, if there is a way in Camunda there to execute some blocks after a process instance is deleted. Let's say a process is running in Camunda and then somebody deletes the process instance using the process instance id.  After process instance is deleted, I want to invoke some activity using a service task in Camunda by listening on to process instance DELETE event. Is that possible in Camunda ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: boundary interrupt]

If you want some process tasks to run when an event happended that shoul cancel the running instance, I would explicitely model this as shown in the picture. Do not cancel the instance via java/rest api, instead send a signal and let the process react. 
That way, you not only gain the freedom to use whatever BPMN execution you desire, it also will be visible in your model and not hidden in code.